# Are conditional scripts possible using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

In `SQL` the following structure is possible

```
IF <condition>
BEGIN
    <do something> 
END;
```

Can I use conditions in a similar way within `MDX` ?

---

**EDIT**
Specifically I'd like to somehow test if a set exists and use that as the condition in the `IF` statement.

```
IF TheFollowingReturnsRow(
          select * 
          from   $SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_SETS
          where  SET_NAME = 'Set_Custom' and 
                 CUBE_NAME = 'MyCube') THEN
      <do something>
END IF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, it is definitely possible to use IF statements in MDX:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145517.aspx

```
SCOPE ([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS);
IF Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] THEN this = 10 END IF;
END SCOPE;
```

Other alternatives include the IIF(Logical_Expression, Expression1, Expression2) and the CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END struct.

Comment: +1 thanks for info - maybe possible but still not sure - I've amended the OP with more specific details.

Answer (score 2):

I think MDX is mainly aimed to be a query language, and hence the `SELECT` statement is the most evolved statement. There are some other **DML** statements like `UPDATE CUBE`, `DRILLTHROUGH`, or `CALL`, but except for `UPDATE`, they all just read data, and are used less frequently.

Then, there are some **DDL** commands, but these are limited to slight adaptations of the existing cube or your current query session, you cannot create new cubes or dimensions using MDX. The "real DDL commands" for SSAS that create cubes or change dimensions etc. are XMLA commands, not MDX statements.

**DCL** statements like `GRANT` or `REVOKE` are not available in MDX.

And for the fourth category of statements that you find in SQL, the **procedural statements** like `if` statements (as opposed to `if` expressions) or looping constructs, as well as server side cursors, MDX does not offer any support as well. These statements are the part of SQL that is not very standardized between different DBMSes like Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, mySQL, to name just a few, while basic DML and DDL is more or less standardized - and to some extent all major relational databases support ANSI SQL. Even for relational databases, this is often a later add-on used mainly in stored procedures, triggers (as a special case of procedures), and batches. MySQL was widely used for many years without having support for these statements which were only introduced in version 5.

For stored procedures, Analysis Services relies on COM (deprecated) and .net, where you have full blown procedural features, and just makes its object model available to .net or COM. Anyway, stored procedure support is limited to functions returning one object (which may be as complex as an MDX set containing a lot of data), or procedures returning result sets. The latter cannot interact with other MDX statements, but just be called with `CALL procname(parameters)`. And for batches, MDX just relies on the hosting environment that calls the batch to do all the conditional branching and looping.

And in fact, MDX has a much more restricted use than SQL, so to some extent, it is just a ["domain specific language"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), that is very good for some purposes, but has many weaknesses in areas that it is not intended for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving all such conditional logic to cube calculation script if possible.
There it is possible to use scope statements which are much more efficient.

Cube calculation script is stored at the server side SSAS. You can have calculations and some other logic defined. These will be available to MDX queries. For example you can create new members and also new sets. Also it is possible to override the values loaded/calculated if needed. Here is a simple explanation on how it works http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/AmitK/sql-server-bi/65/implementing-calculations-in-ssas-using-mdx-part1

If I use the example given by Dan. You can even do things like

SCOPE ([Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS);
    SCOPE ( [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]);
        this = 10;
    END SCOPE;
END SCOPE;

If conditions are very slow, but after such a conversion, they should work at a reasonable speed.

Comment: +1 as I'm intrigued by your answer - although some expansion of this answer would be really nice. What do you mean by "cube calculation script" ?

Comment: Cube calculation script is stored at the server side.

Comment: ...is it the script responsible for the processing of the cube?

Comment: Added more information in the original answer since I cant have a long comment.

Comment: thanks for reference - I'll need to talk with our cube designers / administrators.